# How can I impose decimalFormat on the result of a method?

Tags: java, decimalformat

I have this code:

```
public double theInterest(){     
        return (accountBalance*i) +accountBalance;
```

My question is, is there a way I can impose DecimalFormat to the result of the equation so that it will display up to 2 decimal places?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: As HFOE hints, you need to understand the difference between a *numerical value* and the *form of presentation* of that value.  `double` is a way to represent a *value*, and carries with it no inherent visual format.  If you do  `System.out.println(someDouble);` you get the "default" formatting that `println` chooses for `someDouble` -- not any formatting carried in the *value* named `someDouble`.  To get a different format you need to specify the desired format explicitly, using one of several formatting techniques.

Comment: (And the output (ie, *value*) of a "separate formatting technique" will be a `String`, not a `double`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is as posted nonanswerable since the method returns a double, and DecimalFormat can only return a String. It makes no sense to try to return a formatted *double*.  I don't recommend that you change the method, but consider creating a separate method, say `getInterestString()` that takes the result of `theInterest()`, and formats it with your DecimalFormatter and then returns this formatted String.

i.e.,

```
public String getInterestString() {
  NumberFormat moneyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
  return moneyFormat.format(theInterest();
}
```

Or more generally,

```
private NumberFormat moneyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

public String currencyFormat(double numberValue) {
  moneyFormat.format(numberValue);
}
```

Edit: and as svc well states, you should strive to avoid using floating point numbers for monetary calculations as the inaccuracies matter. Better to use BigDecimal.

Comment: One more thing to add is that usage of `double` to deal with money is discouraged.

Comment: @svz: amen to that! double is too inaccurate to be used for real monetary calculations. Answer edited to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `double` at all for financial work. Typically, you use a `BigDecimal` where your numbers are valued by the lowest currency unit for your country:

```
BigDecimal tenDollars = new BigDecimal(1000L, 2);
// Alternatively, use the BigDecimal(BigInteger, int) constructor.
```

You can set the rounding mode by using `MathContext`s. Internally, you store the BigDecimal for your currency values; only when you display to the user do you convert to a string using a format.